# windows 2003 server licence issues

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I have a 2003 R2 std OEM  English Licence

Can I use it in the same machine, but installing from a *spanish*  std retail media?

I haven't the original disk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did Microsoft say when you asked them?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are very low unless the media is from the same OEM, even then it may not work. You should contact the OEM, if the media is from the same OEM.